# Elasticity of Origami Materials

Tags: elasticity, continuum-mechanics

A few origami structures have elastic properties. Suppose that I have a structure, made from origami techniques, what factors affect the elasticity of the structure apart from the quality of the paper used? How does tessellations and folding patterns affect the elasticity? Is it possible to mathematically quantify this property?

Also, is it possible for me to determine the coefficient of elasticity experimentally? Can someone help me with the experiment if it is possible?

Thanks in Advance;)

Comment: Could you point us to some examples or information? There may be nobody on here who knows much about origami, and what you mean by elastic may not be what we would mean.

Comment: I think this might help --- https://www.google.co.in/url?q=http://www.lps.ens.fr/~adda/papiers/PRE2016.pdf&sa=U&ved=0ahUKEwjfxLHF2YvaAhWBMo8KHcBgAg8QFggUMAM&usg=AOvVaw3yL_UPeMHfX6DsWE7Uqi3Z

Comment: I think you are referring to the ease with which an origami structure can be deformed, this property is not elaticitiy, but stiffness or flexibility, and it depends on both the quality of the paper and the geometry of the structure. Of course, if you compute the stiffness matrix of the structure (via a discretization) you would get mathematical characterizations of the stiffness or flexibility.